# Vuejs2- Issue in vue-form-generator

Tags: vuejs2

I am using "vue-form-generator" plugin for loading fields dynamically but I have encountered an error

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. found in vue-form-generator

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <vue-form-generator :schema="schema" :model="model" :options="formOptions"></vue-form-generator>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueFormGenerator from "vue-form-generator";

Vue.use(VueFormGenerator);

export default {
  components: { VueFormGenerator },
  data: () => ({

    model: {             
      id: 1,
      name: "John Doe",
      password: "J0hnD03!x4",
      skills: ["Javascript", "VueJS"],
      email: "john.doe@gmail.com",
      status: true
    },

    schema: {
      fields: [{
        type: "input",
        inputType: "text",
        label: "ID (disabled text field)",
        model: "id",
        readonly: true,         
        disabled: true
      },{
        type: "input",
        inputType: "text",
        label: "Name",
        model: "name",
        placeholder: "Your name",
        featured: true,
        required: true
      },{
        type: "input",
        inputType: "password",
        label: "Password",
        model: "password",
        min: 6,
        required: true,
        hint: "Minimum 6 characters",
        validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string
      },{
        type: "select",
        label: "Skills",
        model: "skills",      
        values: ["Javascript", "VueJS", "CSS3", "HTML5"]
      },{
        type: "input",
        inputType: "email",
        label: "E-mail",
        model: "email",
        placeholder: "User's e-mail address"
      },{
        type: "checkbox",
        label: "Status",
        model: "status",
        default: true
      }]
    },

    formOptions: {
      validateAfterLoad: true,
      validateAfterChanged: true
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To use](https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator#usage) it as local component, you should use this syntax

```
import VueFormGenerator from "vue-form-generator";

//component javascript
export default{
  components:{
    "vue-form-generator": VueFormGenerator.component
  }
}
```

If you use

```
import VueFormGenerator from "vue-form-generator";

Vue.use(VueFormGenerator);
```

then it already registered `VueFormGenerator` as global. You don't need to register in `components` section of your code.

Here is our code with local component:

```
<template>
    <vue-form-generator :schema="schema" :model="model" :options="formOptions"></vue-form-generator>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueFormGenerator from "vue-form-generator";

export default {
  components:{
    "vue-form-generator": VueFormGenerator.component
  },
  data: () => ({

    model: {             
      id: 1,
      name: "John Doe",
      password: "J0hnD03!x4",
      skills: ["Javascript", "VueJS"],
      email: "john.doe@gmail.com",
      status: true
    },

    schema: {
      fields: [{
        type: "input",
        inputType: "text",
        label: "ID (disabled text field)",
        model: "id",
        readonly: true,         
        disabled: true
      },{
        type: "input",
        inputType: "text",
        label: "Name",
        model: "name",
        placeholder: "Your name",
        featured: true,
        required: true
      },{
        type: "input",
        inputType: "password",
        label: "Password",
        model: "password",
        min: 6,
        required: true,
        hint: "Minimum 6 characters",
        validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string
      },{
        type: "select",
        label: "Skills",
        model: "skills",      
        values: ["Javascript", "VueJS", "CSS3", "HTML5"]
      },{
        type: "input",
        inputType: "email",
        label: "E-mail",
        model: "email",
        placeholder: "User's e-mail address"
      },{
        type: "checkbox",
        label: "Status",
        model: "status",
        default: true
      }]
    },

    formOptions: {
      validateAfterLoad: true,
      validateAfterChanged: true
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

Comment: No it's not working. I have copied ur code & paste in my file. It shows error such as **  [Vue warn]: Error compiling template: ** etc.,

Comment: Did you remove `Vue.use(VueFormGenerator);`?

Comment: Do u know how to update the "vue-form-generator" plugin for vuejs2 ??. Now my current version of the plugin is "vue-form-generator v0.6.1"

Comment: `npm install vue-form-generator@2.2.2 --save`

Comment: I have updated the version. Don' have an error but page becomes empty. Not even a single field appear.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Happy coding!

Comment: Actually there was a property name conflicts between "vee-validate" and "vue-form-generator" plugin, that's why empty page appeared

Comment: I have changed the configuration of "vee-validate" plugin like this . 
`const config = {
  fieldsBagName: 'inputs ', 
  errorBagName: 'vErrors'
};                                                                            Vue.use(VeeValidate, config);`